# Content of my app cutting off in landscape mode

Tags: android, xml, android-studio, android-layout, android-relativelayout

I'm a beginner in android development. I've made a single screen app but the content of the app is cutting off in landscape mode. It's a really simple app which shows the details of a shop. The app runs perfectly fine in portrait mode but when I switch it to landscape mode, some of the textviews disappear. I can't figure out what's wrong.
Here's the code:

```
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity"
android:background="@color/black">
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/toptitle"
    android:text="Try Our Mouthwatering Pani-Puri"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingTop="30dp"
    android:paddingBottom="20dp"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:textSize="25sp"
    android:fontFamily="cursive"
    android:textColor="@color/white"
    />
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/image"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
    android:src="@drawable/panipuri"
    android:layout_below="@id/toptitle"/>
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/detail"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textColor="@color/white"
    android:layout_below="@id/image"
    android:text="Details"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:textSize="20dp"
    android:paddingTop="20dp"
    android:paddingLeft="20dp"
    android:paddingRight="20dp"

    />
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/icon"
    android:layout_below="@id/detail"
    android:layout_width="30dp"
    android:layout_height="30dp"
    android:layout_margin="35dp"
    android:src="@drawable/ocation"/>
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/location"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/icon"
    android:text="Nahar chowk, Sipahi tola, Near Durga Mandir,Purnia"
    android:layout_below="@id/detail"
    android:textColor="@color/white"
    android:paddingTop="35sp"
    android:textSize="15sp"
    android:paddingRight="15dp"
    android:fontFamily="monospace"/>
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/watch"
    android:layout_below="@id/icon"
    android:layout_width="30dp"
    android:layout_height="30dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="35dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="35sp"
    android:src="@drawable/imgicon"/>
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/timing"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/watch"
    android:text="Operates between 9 AM to 11 PM"
    android:layout_below="@id/location"
    android:textColor="@color/white"
    android:paddingTop="35sp"
    android:paddingRight="15dp"
    android:textSize="15dp"
    android:fontFamily="monospace"/>
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/description"
    android:layout_below="@id/timing"
    android:layout_width="30dp"
    android:layout_height="30dp"
    android:layout_margin="35sp"
    android:src="@drawable/description"/>
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/des"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/description"
    android:layout_below="@id/timing"
    android:textSize="15sp"
    android:textColor="@color/white"
    android:paddingTop="35sp"
    android:fontFamily="monospace"
    android:text="Home Delivery available\nRs 10 for 8 pieces.\n"/>
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Contact us:+91-6277665544 "
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:textColor="@color/white"
    android:textSize="16sp"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    android:background="@color/purple_500"/>
   </RelativeLayout>
```

[portrait mode screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HsBGX.jpg)
[landscape mode screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oqmVZ.jpg)

Comment: <ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/ScrollView01"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
  ------- here your Relative Layout code ------
</ScrollView>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome you on `StackOverFlow`.

For a better UX you should create a separate layout for landscape.
This is very easy:

- Create a folder parallel to `layout` folder with name `layout-land`.
- Copy the layout file(the original layout file) into `layout-land` folder.
- Modify view's(viz dimensions, positions, etc) to fit into landscape
  mode

Something like this :
**res/layout-land/activity_main.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    android:background="@color/black">
   <TextView
       android:id="@+id/toptitle"
       android:text="Try Our Mouthwatering Pani-Puri"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
       android:textSize="25sp"
       android:fontFamily="cursive"
       android:textColor="@color/white"
       />
   <ImageView
       android:id="@+id/image"
       android:layout_width="250dp"
       android:layout_height="250dp"
       android:scaleType="centerCrop"
       android:src="@drawable/panipuri"
       android:layout_below="@id/toptitle"
       android:layout_margin="8dp"/>
   <TextView
       android:id="@+id/detail"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:textColor="@color/white"
       android:layout_toEndOf="@id/image"
       android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
       android:layout_alignTop="@id/image"
       android:gravity="center"
       android:text="Details"
       android:textSize="20sp"
       android:paddingTop="8dp"
       android:paddingLeft="8dp"
       android:paddingRight="8dp"

       />
   <ImageView
       android:id="@+id/icon"
       android:layout_below="@id/detail"
       android:layout_alignStart="@id/detail"
       android:layout_width="30dp"
       android:layout_height="30dp"
       android:layout_margin="35dp"
       android:src="@drawable/ocation"/>
   <TextView
       android:id="@+id/location"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_toRightOf="@id/icon"
       android:text="Nahar chowk, Sipahi tola, Near Durga Mandir,Purnia"
       android:layout_below="@id/detail"
       android:textColor="@color/white"
       android:paddingTop="35sp"
       android:textSize="15sp"
       android:paddingRight="15dp"
       android:fontFamily="monospace"/>
   <ImageView
       android:id="@+id/watch"
       android:layout_below="@id/icon"
       android:layout_alignStart="@id/detail"
       android:layout_width="30dp"
       android:layout_height="30dp"
       android:layout_marginLeft="35dp"
       android:layout_marginRight="35sp"
       android:src="@drawable/imgicon"/>
   <TextView
       android:id="@+id/timing"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_toRightOf="@id/watch"
       android:text="Operates between 9 AM to 11 PM"
       android:layout_below="@id/location"
       android:textColor="@color/white"
       android:paddingTop="35sp"
       android:paddingRight="15dp"
       android:textSize="15sp"
       android:fontFamily="monospace"/>
   <ImageView
       android:id="@+id/description"
       android:layout_below="@id/timing"
       android:layout_alignStart="@id/detail"
       android:layout_width="30dp"
       android:layout_height="30dp"
       android:layout_margin="35sp"
       android:src="@drawable/description"/>
   <TextView
       android:id="@+id/des"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_toRightOf="@id/description"
       android:layout_below="@id/timing"
       android:textSize="15sp"
       android:textColor="@color/white"
       android:paddingTop="35sp"
       android:fontFamily="monospace"
       android:text="Home Delivery available\nRs 10 for 8 pieces.\n"/>
   <TextView
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:text="Contact us:+91-6277665544 "
       android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
       android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
       android:textColor="@color/white"
       android:textSize="16sp"
       android:layout_margin="16dp"
       android:background="@color/purple_500"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

- you should use `textSize` value in `sp`.

If you want to have the latest UI elements in your app. You should give a try to  [ConstraintLayout](https://developer.android.com/training/constraint-layout)

**Happy Coding**

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried wrapping your layout in a ScrollView? That might help. Are you using weights? Like

```
<ScrollView> *CONTENT* </ScrollView>
```

It seems like there's just not enough space to fit it all. You might also want to look into adding a different layout file for horizontal configurations that fit better

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to rethink a better layout for the **landscape**. You're certainly don't want to use a `ScrollView` here. For example: Place the `Details` and `Contact us` by right side of the image. Put your desired **portrait** layout in **layout** folder and **layout-land** for the **landscape**.